# Error executing DDL "create table in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, ddl, create-table

I want to save some data coming from the request. for that, I created some entity classes. but why I et this exception?

```
Error executing DDL "create table body_datum (body_datum_id integer not null, key varchar(255), value varchar(255), value_type varchar(255), primary key (body_datum_id)) engine=InnoDB" via
```

Here are my properties.

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/loadtestdb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Here is my model classes.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class BodyDatum {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer bodyDatumId;

    private String key;

    private String value;

    private String valueType;
}
```

Product class like this

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long pId;
    private String productName;
    private int pQty;
    private int price;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
}
```

In the database, the Product table has created.

Why get such an error?

Thanks.

Comment: When do you have this exception ? When you start your application ? How are created your entities ?

Comment: Table creation is done by Hibernate, not by Spring (Data). You don't show the full error, but I'd guess it is either a dialect problem, i.e.  that you are not using the correct database dialect and therefore the generated SQL does not match the expectations of your database, or the database user doesn't have the necessary privileges to create the table.

Comment: @RUAROThibault.  Yes, when I start my application. I just created Database and then created entities as above mentioned then run the program. problem is the Product table created. problem is in other entities.

Comment: @JensSchauder Here is another stack trace .. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(255), value varchar(255), value_type varchar(255), primary key (body_dat' at line 1

Comment: Please don't put stacktraces in comments. Due to the lack of formatting they are almost impossible to read. But you can edit your question and add the stacktrace there. Format it as code for best readability.

Comment: @JensSchauder I found the answer.  RUARO is correct

Comment: Great, go ahead and upvote and accept their answer.

Comment: @JensSchauder Thank you too also, bro. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the attribute "key" is reserved word for SQL. Rename your attribute like that :

```
@Data
@Entity
public class BodyDatum {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer bodyDatumId;

    private String bodyDatumkey;

    private String value;

    private String valueType;
}
```

Comment: you saved my day. However, my was using the reserved keyword `date`. I think the error `invalid identifier bla bla` is not expressive at all.

Comment: Didn't know that company is also a keyword. Your answer really helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was on the same boat.

Beside the MySQL reserved word issue mentioned by @RUARO, I made another mistake, which makes the issue persist even after I replaced column names with non-reserved words:

In `spring.datasource.url` field in `application.properties`, I should specify the database name at the end of the connection url, i.e.

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabasename`

instead of

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306`

Answer (score 0):

Configure the `application.properties` file.

```
project > src > main > resources > application.properties
```

Configure Hibernate Dialect according to your Java version.

For `MySql 5` use `MySQL5Dialect` or for `MySql 8` use `MySQL8Dialect`

Like this:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

**key is a reserved keyword in mysql. Change your column name to something else, for example: 'keys'-- This error mostly gets when we are using reserved words in databases.**

***Reserved Words in Mysql*** -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

***Reference*** --
https://java.tutorialink.com/how-to-resolve-error-executing-ddl-commands-in-spring-boot/

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes for the key column name:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class BodyDatum {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer bodyDatumId;

    @Column(name = "`key`")
    private String key;

    private String value;

    private String valueType;
}
```