# Working non-working Hibernate Derby error

Tags: hibernate-mapping, spring-annotations

I have this very simple entity with the exact same annotations I use prior to adding it to the project.  I get the stacktrace below,shown and also, not shown, when adding the FK constaint. The error occurs whether I use the primitive or object for the index.  Everything seems correct, can someone edify me?  ty.

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int user_id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error
> executing DDL "create table user (user_id integer not null, email
> varchar(255), name varchar(255), password varchar(255), primary key
> (user_id))" via JDBC Statement    at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]

Answer (score 0):

I know, I know DTFS, [Sorry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59788078/error-executing-ddl-create-table-in-spring-data-jpa), for the clutter and lost cycles of attention;)